# flatMap implementation in Scala

Tags: scala

In *Functional Programming in Scala* chapter 4 we are provided the following definitions for `map`, `getOrElse` and `flatMap` for the `Option` type:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
  case Some(x) => Some(f(x))
  case _ => None
}

def getOrElse[B>:A](default: => B): B = this match {
  case Some(x) => x
  case _ => default
}

def flatMap[B](f: A => Option[B]): Option[B] = 
  map(f) getOrElse None
```

I get what `flatMap` is doing, but I don't get how the call `map(f)` in `flatMap`'s definition works.  `f` has `A => Option[B]` as its type in `flatMap`, yet we seem to be able to call `map`, which expects a function of type `A => B`, with `f`. The call `getOrElse None` is obviously the key, but I don't understand how it allows us to call `map(f)` in `flatMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `flatMap` and pass the function `A => Option[B]`, `flatMap` calls `map` and passes the same function, **but** the `B` in `flatMap` is not same `B` as in `map`. For example, if you pass some

```
Int => Option[String]
```

Then for `map`, `B = Option[String]` and will return `Option[Option[String]]`.

Thus the `getOrElse` in `flatMap` to get the will either retrieve the inner `Option[B]` or return `None`.

Comment: Makes sense... but why do I get the following error when I comment out the call to getOrElse

-------------------------------------------
 type mismatch;
[error]  found   : A => fpinscala.errorhandling.Option[B]
[error]  required: A => B
[error]     map(f) //getOrElse None

----------------------------------------
It seems like the call to map is failing

Comment: If you remove the `getOrElse` then you have `Option[Option[B]]` instead of `Option[B]`

Comment: Yes I get that - but why should the call to map fail just because I comment that out. I know the call to getOrElse is essential for flatMap do to its "flattening", but why should the call to map care. It seems like from the error message that map is saying "you cant call me with a function with the type A=>Option[B], I require: A=> B. Am I interpreting the compiler error wrong?

Comment: its not that the call to map fails, it's that the result of that expression is not the type that you said would be the result of the entire function. if you were to change it to "val x = map(f); true" it would no longer be complaining about what is going on with map, but it would say that "true" is not an Option[B], its just looking for the last expression in the block to be of type Option[B], in this case, if map(f) is going to result in an Option[B] then f must be a A=>B not an A=>Option[B]

Answer (score 3):

`B` is just a name for the variable type parameter. It only has meaning within its scope. In other words `B` in `map` and `flatMap` definitions do not have to be the same, they are completely different parameters.

The could have written absolutely equivalently:

```
def flatMap[C](f: A => Option[C]): Option[C] = 
  map(f) getOrElse None
```

Now, in this terms, it is easy to see, that `map` used here has `Option[C]` as the value for its type parameter.